# Using a stub instead of a concrete object as a parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Is it always necessary to create and pass in a stub into a method as a parameter, even if I can instantiate that object being passed in to the method without any problems.

ex. I want to test this method below and it takes in a TargetDataRanger object as a parameter. Should I a.) stub it out and pass it in b.) break the dependency and put it behind a interface then stub it and pass it in c.) instantiate it and pass it into the method as a concrete object.

In this case below I can get away with using the concrete object but is that wise and does it break some testing rules or something?

```
public virtual Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> ResolveDates(ISeries comparisonSeries, TargetDateRanger sourceRanger)
    {
        Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> dates = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();

        foreach (DateTime keyDate in sourceRanger.ValidDates)
            dates.Add(keyDate, this.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, keyDate));

        return dates;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what `TargetDateRanger.ValidDates` does. Assuming you can completely control what that property returns from your unit test, there's no reason to separately mock it out. If it hits the database, has some internal logic, depends on something like `DateTime.Now`, etc. then you'll need to mock it.

Basically, you want the "environment" of a unit test to be completely under your control so that you have predictable results and can quickly pinpoint the failing code. If `ValidDates` has a possibility of returning wrong results, then you'd want to unit test that separately and mock it in this case (so that "bad results" don't cause your `ResolveDates` method to fail, since the problem doesn't reside there).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default parameter.

```
void print(int a, string b = "default")
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In unit testing, I test mine as stand alone. I break it out, have a driver set up that I can pump variables into (if it is meant to receive them) and a stub so I can view the expected results. I feel it's a better test philosophy for me, but I am relatively new to programming, so I find this way of testing me teaches me a lot at the same time.

Once that's done, I integrate it into the larger system, re-test it with a new driver and stub output, verify the entire flow works.

I can't say there is something inherently wrong using the concrete method, especially if it's a small piece of a small program... But, I like breaking things out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a Unit test for this method, I think better to isolate/fake out any external dependencies. The problem is that if you don't, for example if someone make a change to the ValidateDates method, then your test would fail for the wrong reason. On the other had you are also testing what is inside the ValidateDates method. This means you are probably tempting to test multiple things. Also this might prevent you giving good/specific name for the test.

Remember you can Unit test ValidateDates method separately/in isolation.

It is important that you want to break as much as dependencies as test small piece of logic/behavior in isoloation. This way you get real value of Unit Tests IMO.